# How do I custom a page that doesn't exist in the page list?

Tags: templates, archive-template

Many custom post types have their own archive page which doesn't exist in the page list, but I am able to customize these pages by finding the archive's template file. But for some other instances, I couldn't find such template files. For example, Buddyboss's register page such as this one:https://fedlearningcenter.com/register/

By default, there isn't a nav bar on the page. How do I find the corresponding file or filter so I can add a nav bar to the page? I think this is a general WP question because it applies to many theme or plugins.

Comment: If you're running a theme yourself, you can use (or write) a small plugin that will show the current template.

Comment: I've tried to install the plugin called "Reveal Template", it does display template file on regular pages, however not on the page I mentioned in my question. I tried the shortcode and php described on this page https://www.greengeeks.com/tutorials/current-template-wordpress/#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20easily%20find,click%20on%20Appearance%20%3E%20Reveal%20Template none of them works.

Comment: I suppose, this is either Buddyboss- or Elementor- or WooCommerce-related question, not WordPress-related. Look at the `<body>` classes and find out the ID of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very usefull plugin when developping is [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/)
In the template section, you'll be able to find the template or template part used.